# How to call properties of a struct instance with it's names

Tags: c++, struct

I have a structure named **informations**,

```
struct informations {
    char no[12];
    char name[16];
    int exam1, exam2;
    float result;
    char letter[3];
}
```

I'm storing **informations** of students in files. I can read/write files and other things. I want to sort all **students (instances of informations structure)** by all properties that structure has *(in this case, ["no", "name", "exam1", "exam2", "result", "letter"])*.

I have a sort function, it sorts for a property, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    for(int o = 0; o < 99; o++) {
        if(students[i].result > students[i + 1].result) {
            container = students[i];
            students[i] = students[i + 1];
            students[i + 1] = container;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is, works fine for sorting all students by their **result** property, but I want to sort students by their all properties differently without duplicating the above code for all properties. I have ideas about to do this but I don't know how to apply these ideas into code,

1. Store all struct properties in an array,

   `string properties[6] = ["no", "name", "exam1", "exam2", "result", "letter"];`
2. Iterate over the properties array,
3. In iteration loop, use the above sorting function by iterated property

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: C++ does not work this way, sorry.

Comment: Is this same for C language @SamVarshavchik?

Comment: Yes, it is. Neither C nor C++ work this way.

Comment: Alright, thanks @SamVarshavchik :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but without reflection (which C++ does not have) it's not trivial to do.

You can reduce duplication by switching from your quadratic implementation to `std::sort`, then write a bunch of comparators for each sort criterion. Those ought to be as simple as `return student.result < student.result`, where `result` is whatever member you wish to compare (though this is more complex for arrays and C-strings!).

Comment: Is this same for C language?

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN Yes.

Comment: Is there any way to do your advice in C? @LighthnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN Same way! But with `qsort` instead probably.